# how to replace data("id") in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

i had nestable but i want to change

```
data-id="12"
```

to

may be Max data-id equals 17

and than I want to the change the data-id value

```
data-id="39"
```

Here is code:

```html
<!--before-->
<div class="dd" id="nestable">
<ol class="dd-list" id="depth1_ol">
<li data-id="12"><div class="dd-item">Item 12</div></li>
</ol>
</div>

<!--after-->
<div class="dd" id="nestable">
<ol class="dd-list" id="depth1_ol">
<li data-id="39"><div class="dd-item">Item 39....</div></li>
</ol>
</div>
```

how can do this??

Comment: your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: how to do what? What you are already doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is a bit a unclear but I'm assuming that you need to change the `data-id` attribute. Well, to change the value using jQuery you can use the `data` function like below...

```
$("li").data("id", "39");
```

however, be aware that this will not change the actual DOM element, it will be stored in memory for further manipulation within the jQuery framework. If you want to change the DOM directly, then use the `attr` function as below...

```
$("li").attr("data-id", "39");
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually data attribute is not visible in html.The `.data()` method allows us to attach data of any type to DOM elements in a way that is safe from circular references and therefore from memory leaks.

```
$("div#nestable ol li").data("id" , 39);
$("div#nestable ol li").find(".dd-item").text("Item 39");
```